# webpack - ошибки в сборке - Переменная среды NODE_ENV-production webpack не определена

Tags: html, css, node.js, webpack, sass

Какие моменты кода отвечают за ошибки, что нужно исправить:

**Первая ошибка** при запуске npm run production:

```
Переменная среды NODE_ENV-production webpack не определена
```

**Вторая ошибка** происходит в следующем: браузер не видит картинку, подключённую через свойство *background* , но подключенную напрямую через *img* видит. Как я поняла, там почему-то не тот путь указывается, то есть когда через *img* - он ищет изображение в нужной папке img, а когда через *background* , то ищет почему-то в папке css , но что-то я не соображаю как это изменить...

И, собственно, **package.json**

```
{
  "name": "webpack-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "webpack module sample",
  "main": "src/js/app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "watch": "webpack --watch",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open",
    "production": "set NODE_ENV-production webpack"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefix": "^1.0.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.6.1",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.4",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "css-loader": "^3.1.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
    "file-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "imagemin-webpack-plugin": "^2.4.2",
    "img-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "postcss-cli": "^6.1.3",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "svg-url-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.3",
    "webpack": "^4.38.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.6",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.7.2"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path'); 
const webpack = require('webpack'); 


const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const ImageminPlugin = require('imagemin-webpack-plugin').default;
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');


var isProduction = (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production');


module.exports = {
       context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),


    entry: {

        app: [
            './js/app.js',
            './scss/style.scss'
        ],
    },


    output: {
        filename: 'js/[name].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),                
    }, 

    // devServer configuration 
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './app'
    },

    devtool: (isProduction) ? '' : 'inline-source-map',

    module: {
        rules: [
            //scss
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader:'css-loader',
                            options: { sourceMap: true}
                        },
                        {
                            loader:'postcss-loader',
                            options: { sourceMap: true}
                        },
                        {
                            loader:'sass-loader',
                            options: { sourceMap: true}
                        },
                    ],
                    fallback: 'style-loader'
                })
            },

            {
                test: /\.(png|gif|jpe?g)$/,
                loaders: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name: '[path][name].[ext]',
                        },
                    },
                    'img-loader',
                ]
            },
        ],
    },

    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin(
            './css/[name].css'
        ),

        new CleanWebpackPlugin (),

        new CopyWebpackPlugin (
            [
                { from: './img', to: 'img'}
            ],
            {
                ignore: [
                    {glob:'svg/*'},
                ]
            }
        ),
    ],
}

if (isProduction) {
    module.exports.plugins.push (
        new UglifyJSPlugin( {
            sourceMap: true
        }),
    );

    module.exports.plugins.push (
        new ImageminPlugin({
            test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)$/
        }),
    );

    module.exports.plugins.push (
        new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
            minimize: true 
        }),
    );
}
```

ну и ещё есть **postcss.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        require('autoprefixer')
    ]
}
```

В общем вот, я точно уже знаю, что исправлять.

Comment: `NODE_ENV=production`. Равно, а не дефис